# How can I bookmark all search results in PyCharm/JetBrains IDE?

Tags: python, android-studio, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In a large-scale project, sometimes the number of search results is large, and I want to bookmark all the ones found in the search so that I can edit them later. How can I do it?

For example, in the following search, more than 100 items were found, and I want all 100 lines of code to be marked.

[image]

Comment: Do you know that this Find in Files popup shows TOP 100 results only (I mean, if there will be  a lot of matches in some file in can show more, but in general it's top 100 only). In essence, this popup it's just a preview (very advanced one where you can edit the file right away but still...). When searching here it is done *as fast as possible* in multiple random files at once. I suggest you just click on **"Open in Find Window" button** at the bottom and have ALL search results listed in a dedicated tool window (even if there will be over 1,000 of them).

Comment: Regarding bookmarks: why would I need to bookmark 100 lines if I can do the same search again?.. And if I use the aforementioned "Open in Find Window" button, the toolwindow will stay open so I can navigate between files, do other searches etc (if I ping that search results tab ofc).

Comment: If I edit them, they may not show up in the search result later and I have to see the changes through the git status.  But if I can bookmark everything, I can easily find the previous search results, both those that I changed and those that I didn't change.

Comment: Only one by one then (which will take a while .. considering that there is no shortcut to switch between the areas). No better ideas from me right now. The only other option (kind of -- with a big stretch) is use that "Open in Find Window" button and invoke "Export to Text File" there -- at very least you will have some sort of records. try it anyway -- maybe you will be able to combine it with some another tool somehow...

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness, for now, I will mark each line one by one so that maybe a better solution can be found later.

Answer (score 0):

**In general:** sadly, you cannot quickly mass add bookmarks, neither from Find in Files nor Search Results toolwindow.

**I mean:** you can use <kbd>F11</kbd> shortcut for that (Windows keymap)... *but only if you use it when the **focus in the edit/preview area** (where most of the editor shortcuts will work).* The same shortcut will do nothing when the actual search results area is focused. Plus, you would need to manually focus every single desired line for that... and without a dedicated action/shortcut to switch between the areas... using a mouse for that... that will take time...

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171019 -- this ticket asks just that: ability to use bookmarks from the Find in Files results list. Watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified about any progress.

---

Another useful ticket to vote for:

- [IDEA-230848](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230848) -- Add a shortcut to switch between search box and preview editor in 'Find in Files'
- [IDEA-242962](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242962) (and linked tickets) -- Allow keyboard navigation in Find in Files dialog